# Tried using vscode for Java Space in c:\Users\"firstname" "lastname" causes error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFlsS.png)
Tried running java on vscode with the installer they provide which installs extensions required (had the jdk installed already) tried to run a print statement caused this error and by the looks of it the space in my windows user name is causing issues.

Comment: Many programs have problems with spaces (or other special characters) in path names. To be on the safe side change your user name.

Comment: but how ? microsoft accounts require a first name and a last name, tried to change windows account to a local account with name **Abdeai_Saria** but the users folder still has my microsoft account username **Abdeali Saria** on it.

Comment: Hi guys, what's the theme you are using?